# Is it a good idea to hand sew a denim pencil skirt with false cuts instead of using sewing machine?

Tags: sewing

I am thinking of making, as a gift, a custom pencil skirt with a false cut.  I make a rough sketch in order to figure out the appearance of the skirt  (the upper part of the image is how will look in front, and the bottom is how it will look on the side):

[image: Rough Sketch of a skirt]

I was wondering whether it is feasible to hand-sew it instead of using a sewing machine (I assume doing so will take time). The skirt will have a side slit in both sides with some navy-style stripe fabric that covers it.

As for the fabric, I was thinking denim and a light one for the side slits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you can sew on a machine, you can also sew by hand.

**But**

- It will take much longer.
- If the seam is visible you must take special care to sew evenly or it will look ugly.
- It's harder to sew a straight line if you don't mark it on the fabric. (There are special markers that disappear when heated for that reason).

**Is it a good idea?**

For the whole skirt: not really. That would make the whole process take much, *much* more time. If you like hand sewing as a meditative hobby, go for it. If you want to get things done on time, use a machine.

For details like button holes or the insert in the side seam: sure, why not. I've hand sewn a lot of gussets and pockets and complicated seams simply because I didn't know how to wrangle them under the machine.

For seams that have to withstand a lot of strain, a hand sewn back stitch is even better and sturdier than a straight machine stitch.

Comment: I would say that a 'well sewn back stitch' is better than a machine stitch. I have seen too many stitches that would not stand the test.