# How I can calculate how much fabric I need to buy?

Tags: sewing, fabric

I am planning the materials I need for the skirt mentioned in my question [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/10307/1043). It is a pencil skirt with false cuts and I want to order the appropriate amount of fabric.

But I do not know how I can calculate how much fabric I need. Do you have an idea how I can calculate the right amount of fabric I need?

Comment: Do you have a pattern for the skirt? Usually the required amount of fabric is printed on the pattern or you can lay out the pattern pieces and measure the length and width.

Comment: For now I have not a pattern.

Comment: Well, you'll need a pattern, or the skirt won't fit. It's as simple as that. A pencil skirt is a rather tight fitting garment made of curved pieces of fabric. You need a pattern to get the fit right. There are commercial patterns available and some books and old fashion magazines show you how to draft your own pattern. Those usually include how much fabric you need. Alternately, you may "upcycle" an old jeans into a skirt (provided that it still fits). It's best to search for videa tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

There are rule of thumb estimates for standard items of clothing.
If you go to a good fabrics shop the experienced staff may still know them. I do not expect to find them in the instructions for buying online.

They were rough estimates at best and mostly you would buy more than you would need.

The best way to work out what you need will be making the pattern pieces and placing them on a table as wide as your fabric. But remember that many pattern only give half the pieces and you use the fabric folded.